# Extracting just the link in the <a> tag using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Im using selenium in python to do some webscraping and I want to get just the links here.

```html
<ul class="liste-sous-menu">
   <li class="target Menu" id="summary1">
       <a href="../associations/formalites-administratives-association">Formalités administratives d'une 
       association</a>
       <ul class="ul-dossier">
          <li>
              <a href="../associations/creation-association">Création</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm interested just in links in the tag with id `summary1` and not the other links mentioned in the second unordered list
and since I have a long list with id that starts with `summary` I did this code ,  but while refering to it I get just the texts and not the link , do you have any other suggestion?

```
list_of_services = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("liste-sous-menu")
for service in list_of_services:
    # In each element, select the tags
    atags = service.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[starts-with(@id,'summary')]")
    for atag in atags:
        # In each atag, select the href
        href = atag.get_attribute('href')
        # Open a new window
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        # Switch to the new window and open URL
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.get(href)
        sleep(3)
```

So when I want to get the link I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)
```

Comment: You are in a li class without an href. So first go to the a tag and then get the href.

Comment: this is what I did using the `atag.get_attribute` ?

Comment: <li class="target Menu" id="summary1"> This is what you are currently on. Print out the href under that get_attribute.

Comment: you are right , so after that I did `link = service.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")` , but even when I get the link I can't go through with  `drive.get(link)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What happens!**

You are just selecting the `<li>` and not the `<a>`, so you wont get a `href` - Try to use the following xpath to select the `href`

```
//li[starts-with(@id,'summary')]/a
```